# WIX : Create virtual directory under other website than 'Default Web Site'

Tags: iis, wix

I have created an installer where user has option to select a website from dropdown (dropdown will list all available websites) and provide name for virtual directory.

Code:

```
<iis:WebVirtualDir Id="PCVDir" Alias="[VDNAME]" Directory="dir_MDMCenter_0" WebSite="MySelectedWebSite">
        <iis:WebApplication Id="PCWebApp" Name="[VDNAME]" WebAppPool="MyAppPool" />
    </iis:WebVirtualDir>

<iis:WebAppPool Id="MyAppPool" Name="[APPPOOLNAME]" ManagedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" ManagedPipelineMode="integrated" Identity="localSystem" IdleTimeout="0" RecycleMinutes="0">
</iis:WebAppPool>

<iis:WebSite Id="MySelectedWebSite" Description="[MYWEB_WEBSITE_DESCRIPTION]">
    <iis:WebAddress Id="AllUnassigned1" Port="[MYWEB_WEBSITE_PORT]" IP="[MYWEB_WEBSITE_IP]" Header="[MYWEB_WEBSITE_HEADER]" />
</iis:WebSite>
```

When user installs and selects website other than 'Default web site', virtual directory  always gets created in 'Default Web Site'.

**Analysis:**

New website I create runs on port 80. I have stopped Default Web Site as it also runs on port 80.
Now when we install in other website, virtual directory goes under Default Web Site. Seems somewhere in WIX or IIS has binding saying port 80 is mapped to Default Web Site.

In log, I verified values of all the variables (MYWEB_WEBSITE_DESCRIPTION, MYWEB_WEBSITE_PORT) are coming correct. But still application goes under Default Web site.

Can someone please correct me if am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have to create custom actions to populate the drop down box with websites and to install under different website. Please try referring to

http://blog.torresdal.net/2008/10/24/WiXAndDTFUsingACustomActionToListAvailableWebSitesOnIIS.aspx